# Problem With onBoard Wireless Network Card in Lenovo Laptop Ubuntu 15.10v

Tags: networking, drivers, network-manager, lenovo

Not long ago unexpectedly my wifi stop working, luckily i had a usb-wireless-card. when i connect to wifi with my usb-wireless-card it's all ok but when i unplug it it still gives me what wireless access point's are available but when i try to connect an error message appears 
"Connection activation Failure 
 (1) Creating object for path '/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/24' failed in livnm-glib."

what can i do to fix this problem ?

Comment: Please edit and add the output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2`

Comment: The command runs but no output is given.

Comment: now the error message is "Connection activation Failure (1) Creating object for path '/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/30' failed in livnm-glib."

Comment: And `lspci` the Network controller?

Comment: this appears https://www.dropbox.com/s/s0e768isglg8a6f/Screenshot%20from%202016-03-25%2021-57-46.png?dl=0

Comment: i run the  lspci -knn | grep Net -A2 command again and now 30 is 5

Comment: It's better to edit and add the output , maybe you will found a good answer from experts , and you can help others members who have the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the Answer posted by [varunendra](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2239214)

> The smarter way to save the security key, along with other settings is to do it via Network Manager settings (nm-applet menu > "Edit Connections" > "Wireless" tab > double-click your connection > "Security" tab). That is the frontend to handle those key files.
>
> Assuming something might have broken in Network Manager installation while upgrading, you may try to completely purge it, then re-install it. To download the packages in advance (since you'll lost internet connection >as soon as you purge it

```
sudo apt-get install -d --reinstall network-manager network-manager-gnome
```

Then to purge it

```
sudo apt-get purge network-manager-gnome network-manager
```

> To reinstall it (I suggest a reboot in-between) from the downloaded packages, simply

```
sudo apt-get install network-manager-gnome
```